# Simple_form color styling

Tags: css, rubygems, simple-form

Is it possible to change the default color of the `simple_form` input box from grey to another color with CSS?
Here is my CSS:

```css
.simple_form div.input {
    width: 500px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `color`:

```css
.simple_form div.input {
    color: #ff0000; /* red */
}
```

To change border:

```css
.simple_form div.input:focus {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000; /* red */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Any clue how to change the color of the border when you are typing in the form (it turns blue).